# Haskell Depth-First Graph Traversal has Infinite Loop

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, infinite-loop, depth-first-search

I have spent some time recently trying to make a depth-first traversal algorithm in Haskell. However, with my one I would like the function to return a 'visited' list, which has every node visited in order.

Demonstration: with the graph `[('A', "BC"), ('B', "ACD"), ('C', "AB"), ('D', "B")]` the output should be `"ABCBD"` since I am starting on `A` and finishing on `D`.

Here is my code:

```
import Data.List (elemIndex)

trav :: [(Char, String)] -> Char -> Char -> String -> String
trav [] _ _ _ = []
trav graph node endNode visited
    | not (elem node visited) = trav graph node endNode (visited ++ [node])  -- repeat but after adding this node to visited list.
    | node == endNode = visited
    | not (null unvisitedNodes) = trav graph (head unvisitedNodes) endNode visited
    | not (null visited) = if (length prevIndex) > 1 then (trav graph (visited !! (getIndex (head prevIndex) visited)) endNode (visited ++ [(visited !! (getIndex (head prevIndex) visited))])) else (trav graph (head (tail (reverse visited))) endNode (visited ++ [(head (tail (reverse visited)))]))
    | otherwise = visited
    where
        unvisitedNodes = [x | x <- getAttachedVertexes graph node, not (elem x visited)]
        prevIndex = [x | x <- (reverse visited), x < (head (reverse visited))]

getAttachedVertexes :: [(Char, String)] -> Char -> [Char]
getAttachedVertexes graph node = case lookup node graph of
    Just value -> value
    Nothing -> ""

getIndex :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Int
getIndex item list = case elemIndex item list of
    Just index -> index
    Nothing -> error "help"
```

This code actually works fine and outputs the demonstrated ideal output which I wrote above when inputted with the following: `trav [('A', "BC"), ('B', "ACD"), ('C', "AB"), ('D', "B")] 'A' 'D' ""`

However, this code starts an infinite recursion loop when I enter the following input: `trav [('A', "CDE"), ('B', "D"), ('C', "AD"), ('D', "ABC"), ('E', "A")] 'A' 'E' ""`

There is obviously no error message as it's an infinite loop.

---

My thought process:

I have just edited this question with an updated Haskell code, which is the result of the below thinking:

I first thought that part of the problem was that, when backtracking, the node which was backtracked to was added to the `visited` list, meaning that when I do `head (tail (reverse visited))` the item that returns is actually the same node that is currently being traversed.

I 'translated' this code into Python 3, which is the language I have the most experience in, and kept it in Haskell format, i.e. a function containing a series of `if` statements all with a `return` line within them.

Next, I attempted to fix  the above error. It returns the correct output for the first input I said above (`{"A":["B", "C"], "B":["A", "C", "D"], "C":["A", "B"], "D":["B"]}`) however, when I try the second input above (`{"A":['C', 'D', 'E'], "B":['D'], "C":['A','D'], "D":['A','B','C'], "E":['A']}`) it again starts an infinite loop (well, at least until the stack overflows).

Here is said Python code:

```
def trav(graph, node, endNode, visited):
    if node not in visited:
        return trav(graph, node, endNode, (visited + [node]))
    if node == endNode:
        return visited
    unvisitedNodes = [x for x in getAttachedNodes(graph, node) if x not in visited]
    if len(unvisitedNodes) > 0:
        return trav(graph, unvisitedNodes[0], endNode, visited)
    if len(visited) > 0:
        prevIndex = [x for x in reversed(visited) if x < visited[-1]]
        if len(prevIndex) > 1:
            return trav(graph, visited[visited.index(prevIndex[0])], endNode, (visited + [visited[visited.index(prevIndex[0])]]))
        else:
            return trav(graph, visited[-2], endNode, (visited + [visited[-2]]))
    return visited


if __name__ == '__main__':
    graph1 = {"A":["B", "C"], "B":["A", "C", "D"], "C":["A", "B"], "D":["B"]}
    node = input("Node: ")
    endNode = input("EndNode: ")
    graph2 = {"A":['C', 'D', 'E'], "B":['D'], "C":['A','D'], "D":['A','B','C'], "E":['A']}
    visited = []
    print(trav(graph2, node, endNode, visited))
```

I have since re-written the Haskell code, and it now runs exactly the same way in all tested cases as the above Python code. Obviously this only helps those who are capable in Python. I wrote it to hopefully be able to understand the problem. My next edit will be the result of the debugging of this Python code.

I apologise for it's messiness and inefficiency, but I want to mirror as closely as possible the above Haskell code.

Anyway, I included this to hopefully make clearer my algorithm.

In conclusion, the problem was not what I explained I thought it was just above.

Thanks again.

Comment: Why is `B` repeated twice in the output?

Comment: @willeM_VanOnsem  basically the depth-first algorithm searches through every single node, and I want to record the order in which it traverses through each node. In the example I provided, the function starts on 'a', goes to 'b', then 'c', but then it has to go back to 'b' to continue, then it can reach 'd' which is the end node.

Comment: @irainey6-eng: but wouldn't that easily get into a infinite loop: if `a` maps to `b` and `b` to `a` and `c`, it can start ping-ponging between `a` and `b` and never reach `c`.

Comment: Is this (second example) the smallest input which loops? Trying to make the input as small as possible makes it easier to spot problems -- because there's fewer places for them to be hiding. What justifies `head (tail (reverse visited))`? How do you know you will always need to jump back exactly one node? Could there ever be a situation where you must jump back two nodes? Why (not)?

Comment: @willeM_VanOnsem the program is supposed to traverse through only a list of the unvisited neighbouring nodes for each node, not every single neighbouring one, so if the program works correctly, this shouldn't be a problem

Comment: @DanielWagner from my testing, I think the infinite loop occurs when there's more than one backtrack, although I'm not certain if this is right or not. The only time it backtracks is when the current node has no unvisited neighbours. If this happens and it backtracks once, and it still has no unvisited neighbours, hopefully this should mean that it will apply the same case with the same logic, and backtrack another time (if that line works as intended of course, which may be the problem!) Thanks

Comment: for everyone viewing this problem, I may have found part of the problem - I think (with the help of @DanielWagner 's comment above) that whenever it backtracks by one node, it still adds that node to the visited list, so if a second node in a row also has no unvisited neighbouring nodes, it will again 'backtrack' to the second last item, but this time that second last item is actually the node which is currently being examined. I will do some playing around and if I figure out how to solve this I'll post it as an answer.

Comment: Mentioning all nodes you try to visit in the output is not a good idea as the size of the output can exponentially explode.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI i agree, however this is just a function I have made for a challenge, it is not going to be applied on important data in the real world.

Comment: Such output is meaningless anyway. The algorithm tells you that it found a path, but it doesn't show you the path it found. Rather, it dumps its inner working data. Why would anyone ever want such output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just solved this. Here is the updated Haskell code:

```
import Data.List (elemIndex)

trav :: [(Char, String)] -> Char -> Char -> String -> String
trav [] _ _ _ = []
trav graph node endNode visited
    | not (elem node visited) = trav graph node endNode (visited ++ [node])  -- repeat but after adding this node to visited list.
    | node == endNode = visited
    | not (null unvisitedAttachedNodes) = trav graph (head unvisitedAttachedNodes) endNode visited
    | not (null visited) = if not (null attachedNodesWithUnvisited) then (trav graph (head attachedNodesWithUnvisited) endNode (visited ++ [(head attachedNodesWithUnvisited)])) else (trav graph (head (tail (reverse visited))) endNode (visited ++ [head (tail (reverse visited))]))
    | otherwise = visited
    where
        unvisitedAttachedNodes = [x | x <- getAttachedVertexes graph node, not (elem x visited)]
        prevIndex = [x | x <- (reverse visited), x < (head (reverse visited))]
        unvisitedPrevNodes = [x | x <- prevIndex, elem x [y | y <- (getAttachedVertexes graph x), not (elem y visited)]]
        nodeToGoBackTo = visited !! (getIndex (head (reverse unvisitedPrevNodes)) visited)
        attachedNodesWithUnvisited = [nb | nb <- (getAttachedVertexes graph node), (hasUnvisited graph nb visited)]

getAttachedVertexes :: [(Char, String)] -> Char -> [Char]
getAttachedVertexes graph node = case lookup node graph of
    Just value -> value
    Nothing -> ""

hasUnvisited :: [(Char, String)] -> Char -> String -> Bool
hasUnvisited graph node visited = not (null unvisited) where
    unvisited = [x | x <- (getAttachedVertexes graph node), not (elem x visited)]

count :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Int
count item list = length (filter (== item) list)

getIndex :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Int
getIndex item list = case elemIndex item list of
    Just index -> index
    Nothing -> error "help"
```

and here is the updated equivalent Python code:

```
def trav(graph, node, endNode, visited):
    if node not in visited:
        return trav(graph, node, endNode, (visited + [node]))
    if node == endNode:
        return visited
    unvisitedAttachedNodes = [x for x in getAttachedNodes(graph, node) if x not in visited]
    if len(unvisitedAttachedNodes) > 0:
        return trav(graph, unvisitedAttachedNodes[0], endNode, visited)
    if len(visited) > 0:  # needs to backtrack
        attachedNodesWithUnvisited = [nb for nb in graph[node] if has_unvisited(graph, nb, visited)]
        if len(attachedNodesWithUnvisited) > 0:
            return trav(graph, attachedNodesWithUnvisited[0], endNode, visited + [attachedNodesWithUnvisited[0]])
        else:
            return trav(graph, visited[-2], endNode, visited + [visited[-2]])
    return visited
```

I realised that the infinite loop was caused by, whenever backtracking was necessary, the program only went back by one node, but then added that node to the visited list, so `head (tail (reverse visited))` (or Python equivalent `visited[-2]` meant the program kept going between two nodes. As you can see clearly in the new Python translation, I am now going to `visited[-2]` *unless* there is an attached nodes with unvisited neighbouring nodes.

this now works with all the graphs I have tested with it.

Thanks very much for everyone's help!

Comment: Good work, @lrainey6-eng! Glad you figured it out!  I made some comments to my last answer why I think that the issue with indexing and explicitly calculating could have been avoided with a more idiomatically functional approach.  I commend your efforts to translate between Haskell and Python.  If I may be so bold, I would like to advise you to be conscious that Haskell it built on a very different paradigm of computing.  Your understanding and facility with Haskell will be improved if you do not try to shoehorn imperative style approaches into it.

Comment: As Haskelll is based on lambda calculus, "everything" runs on processes of expansion and substitution as found in algebra and illustrated in my answer(s) (I hope). As Python itself includes many features of functional programming (e.g. list comprehensions and map), it might be illuminating to try to translate the strategy that I used into Python.  In my opinion, a person will get farther with Haskell the sooner they are able to unlearn the imperative style approaches.

Comment: @GeoffreyWarne thanks very much - not at all, I agree, and I think my tendency to think of solutions to problems in terms of imperitive structures before I make any program in any language is to blame for this, which itself is caused by my lack of experience in any non-imperitive language. I have only been programming in Haskell for two or three weeks, so I hope to improve. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

@lrainey6-eng,

First, as @willeM_ Van Onsem pointed out in the comments to your question, your trees have loops in them.  Let's try this with different input.  Let's try this for a node list of: [('A', "BC"), ('B', "DE"), ('C', "FG"), ('D', "HI"), ('E', "JK"), ('F', "LM"), ('G', "NO")].  If we start at 'A' and search for 'O', we should expect of path of "ABDHIEJKCFLMGN".  Correct?

```
           A-0
          / \
         /   \
        /     \
       /       \
      /         \
     B-1         C-8 
    / \         / \
   /   \       /   \
  D-2   E-5   F-9   G-12
 / \   / \   / \   / \
H   I J   K L   M N   O
3   4 6   7 10 11 13 14
```

I wasn't able to follow your program, but I wrote my own for comparison.  I would like to try to put it into Python, just for the experience.  Anyway, here is what I came up with:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
-- Necessary for running `quickCheckAll` as `runTests` (see EOF)

import Test.QuickCheck
import Test.QuickCheck.All

-- Just for clarity
type Label = Char
type Node = (Label, [Label])
type Path = [Label]

-- Lazily traverse the depthOrder path, until target is found
pathTo :: [Node] -> Label -> Path
pathTo nodes target = takeWhile (not . (==) target)
                      (depthOrder nodes)

-- Find root -- node label that is not a sub of any other nodes
-- Start with root label and `cons` with expansion of root subs
depthOrder :: [Node] -> Path
depthOrder nodes = root : concatMap (expand nodes) subs
  where
    (root, subs) = head [(l, ss) | (l,ss) <- nodes, l `notElem` allSubs]
    allSubs = concat [subs | (label,subs) <- nodes]

-- Every expansion of a sub label, recursively calls for expansion of the
-- subs that follow from that label
expand :: [Node] -> Label -> Path
expand nodes label = label : concatMap (expand nodes)
                                       (getSubs label nodes)

-- For every sub label we search the node list for a node with that label,
-- and if there is one, get the subs for that node.
getSubs :: Char -> [Node] -> [Char]
getSubs label nodes = safeHead (dropWhile (not . (==) label . fst) nodes)
  where safeHead [] = []
        safeHead ((label,subs):ns) = subs 

----------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- simple expansion of one label into a path, based on depth order with
-- left sub searched befor right sub
prop_expand0 :: Property
prop_expand0 = property (expand [('B',"DE")] 'B' == "BDE")

-- if there is no node label in the node list that matches, the label is a
-- "leaf"
prop_expand1 :: Property
prop_expand1 = property (expand [('A',"BC")] 'Z' == "Z")

-- expanding from a predetermined root
prop_expand2 :: Property
prop_expand2 = property
  (expand [('A',"BC"),('B',"DE"),('C',"FG")] 'A' == "ABDECFG")

-- getting depthOrder for a node list, requires first finding a root
prop_depthOrder0 :: Property
prop_depthOrder0 = property
  (depthOrder [('B',"DE"),('C',"FG"),('A',"BC")] == "ABDECFG")

-- once we have a DEFINITION of the depth order of the node list, a simple
-- 'take' of the order will give us the path to the target label
prop_pathTo0 :: Property
prop_pathTo0 = property
  (pathTo [('A',"BC"),('B',"DE"),('C',"FG")] 'G' == "ABDECF")
  
prop_depthOrder1 :: Property
prop_depthOrder1 = property
  (depthOrder [('A', "BC"), ('B', "DE"), ('C', "FG"), ('D', "HI"),
               ('E', "JK"), ('F', "LM"), ('G', "NO")] == "ABDHIEJKCFLMGNO")
-- which is what we predicted at the outset


-- necessary pieces for running `quickCheckAll` on all our test properties
return []
runTests = $quickCheckAll
```

What should we get if we run:
`pathTo [('t',"Hr"),('h',"ij"),('q',"sT"),('i'," tE"),('T',"r"), (' ',""),('E',"!q"),('H',"e")] 'q'`?

Comment: These are not meant to be trees.

Comment: @n. m. could be an AI: Thanks!  I had to look up DFS for a graph.  Now I understand the problem.  Interesting!

Comment: @GeoffreyWarne thanks very much for your time, I really appreciate it - the only thing is I am trying to make this compatible with graphs as well (which in practice would therefore also be compatible with trees). Basically ideally it would work with any set of nodes with each having at least one connection to another and all nodes being connected as a whole (i.e. no nodes which aren't reachable from any other nodes). Another thing is that ideally the 'visited' list tracks backtracks too - I have run out of space so will explain this in a second comment

Comment: @GeoffreyWarne continuing on from my previous comment, I would like the function to traverse through the graph and track every movement, so an output may look like this: "ABCBD" if there are nodes A through to D but D is only connected to B for example. Thanks again!

Comment: @lrainey6-eng: Yes, I get it now.  Very interesting!  I am hoping that I can adapt the tree method along the lines of: a) modifying the node list to remove fully traversed nodes, or b) checking the path traveled so far.  As you alluded to, there should be some similarity between working on a tree and working on a graph. And thank you, for a fundamental sort of problem that challenges my core understanding!

Comment: @GeoffreyWarne thanks very much, I really appreciate you spending your time on this!

Comment: @GeoffreyWarne I have just solved it and posted an answer, in case you're still interested. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: @lrainey6-eng:  My pleasure!  I won't lie...  I struggled with this, but I learned something.  I posted another answer with revisions to make my original program work on graphs as well as trees.

Comment: @lrainey6-eng:  I will check out your completed program next.  Now that I understand the problem, I would like to see how you solved it.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

In my previous answer (see above) I included a program for depth first search on trees, where the nodes do not loop back on themselves.  It was pointed out to me that the question here involves graphs which can loop back.  Here I will adapt the previous program to also work for graphs in general (including trees).

Adapting the above program for trees to graphs in general required a number of revisions.  Somewhat trivially the function `pathTo` was made to return `Nothing` if there is no clear root node, as there is with a tree.  Instead general graphs use a function called `pathFromTo` which takes a starting point as well as a target label. (Not included in the code below, see previous answer for a start)

The major difference arises in the `expand` function which is the core of the program.  Previously, with just trees we could pass the same list of nodes to every recursive expansion without concern because there would never be a case where an expansion leads to another expansion of itself and an infinite loop.  With graphs, the depth search path requires that each node is removed from the node list when it has been expanded, so it can not be expanded or 'visited` again.

The additional function, `remove`, deletes nodes and subnodes with a given label.  In addition, we previously allowed a node list to contain subnodes that were not explicitly listed as terminal nodes ('leaves') themselves.  This leads to unnecessary complications, so we would have to insist (by way of an invariant) that subnodes are included as nodes like so: `[('A',"BC"),('B',""),('C',"") … ]`.

```
remove nodes label = [(l,[s | s <-ss, s /= label])
                            | (l,ss) <- nodes, l /= label]
```

Because the search path expands down leftmost branches before those to the right, the expansion of subnodes depend on the node lists returned from those to their left.  This means that we can no longer use a simple mapping over all subs equally as we did before with `concatMap (expand nodes) (getSubs label nodes)'.  Now we need to use a recursive function that passes revised node lists to each successive sub expansion.

With these changes the essential program for just trees will work on graphs in general.

Compare:

```
-- Every expansion of a sub label, recursively calls for expansion of the
-- subs that follow from that label
expand :: [Node] -> Label -> Path
expand nodes label = label : concatMap (expand nodes)
                                       (getSubs label nodes)
```

To:

```
-- Every expansion of a subnode label, recursively calls for expansion of
-- the subnodes that follow from THAT label.
-- To avoid loops and 'visiting' nodes more than once, every expansion will
-- remove the node being expanded from derivative expansions.
-- Since leftmost branches are evaluated first, the node list is resolved
-- before passing to the next branch right, and then the branch right of it.
expand :: [Node] -> [Label] -> Path
expand _ [] = ""
expand nodes (label:ls)
  | getSubs label nodes == Nothing = ""             -- no longer in list
                        ++ expand nodes ls          -- cont to other nodes
  | getSubs label nodes == Just ("") = [label]      -- a leaf
                        ++ expand (nodes `remove` [label]) ls
  | otherwise = label : leftPath ++ recOnRSubs      -- left to right
                        ++ expand                   ---- through subnodes
                           (nodes `remove` (label : leftPath ++ recOnRSubs))
                           ls
  where
    (lSub:rSubs) = fromJust (getSubs label nodes)
    leftPath = expand (nodes `remove` [label]) [lSub]
    recOnRSubs = expand (nodes `remove` (label:leftPath)) rSubs

remove :: [Node] -> [Label] -> [Node]
remove nodes visited = [(l, [s | s <- ss, s `notElem` visited])
                               | (l,ss) <- nodes, l `notElem` visited]
```

Note: in the line where it says `otherwise = label : leftPath ++ recOnRSubs …` , I have made the expansion of the leftmost subnode explicit before moving to a recursion on the subnodes to the right.  This is not strictly necessary.  One could use a version of the recursion on subnodes to include the leftmost node as well, but I like how the left path is explicit. It helps orient the reader, I think.

Comment: I see that I am losing points for my answer(s).  Presumably they are getting down-voted because I am "not answering the question".  If you will permit me, I would like to say how my answer does address the original question by way of a deeper understanding of the functional paradigm.

Comment: The original poster discovered the problem to be one of getting the wrong index in telling the program which node to "backtrack" to.  This hints at a divergence between functional and imperative ways of computing.  This strategy is characteristic of an imperative approach where the program has to tell the computer where to go and what to do next.  The use of indexing is rather un-idiomatic for Haskell.  My program is more idiomatic Haskell in that it does not use indexing at all.

Comment: At no point does my program have to tell the computer where it is and where to continue.  Paths are expanded in sequence.  When a path is fully expanded and hits a dead end, it stops, and the computer then continues with the next path in line.  There is no need to explicitly tell the computer where to "backtrack" to.  As the original poster found out on their own, their program had miscalculated the backtracking.  My answer(s) show that adopting a more idiomatic functional strategy would have avoided a imperative-style mistake in the first place.

Comment: thanks very much for this analysis and solution, I really appreciate the time you have spent on this. For anyone else reading this, this is in fact helpful for the solution to my problem, so I would appreciate if no downvotes were given, cheers